# Use a database like mysql to webflow

Tags: database, webflow

I'm currently watching tutorials on how to build website using webflow but I'm curious if it is possible to use a database in webflow. 
What are the best database i can use in a web app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although you could use a database with webflow, normally I would recommend using a web framework if you are wanting to build a web app. There are solutions that work with webflow that make it possible to connect to mysql databases though, like Zapier.

You could use Zapier to connect your webflow project to a mysql database, but I wouldn't recommend this approach, as it may not be as secure, and you will be spending a lot more money over time on subscriptions.

I am using Webflow for building front ends to web applications, but I am building the web apps in Laravel, which is a php web framework, or in Wordpress, which provides a little more options when working with Mysql databases and providing extra functionality.

Hope this helps!